# Meteor collection publishes to much

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a problem with my Meteor sub/pub in that they don't filter the data probably.

My code is as follows:

```
//server.js
Meteor.publish("tasks", function(options){
  return Tasks.find({},options);
});

//routes.js a  waitOn function 
Meteor.subscribe("tasks",{creator:Meteor.userId()})
```

However, each clients gets pushed all tasks and not just the ones that they created. What am I missing here? I am filtering again in the .find method:

```
return Tasks.find({creator:Meteor.userId()},{sort: {createdAt: -1}});
```

But this is obviously not good enough from a security point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the way you written the publish method-

Looks like from subscribe you are trying to send the query and in publish you are putting it as second parameter instead of first

Modify publish to following-

```
//server.js
Meteor.publish("tasks", function(options){
  return Tasks.find(options);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. I specifically looked up the section in the otherwise great DiscoverMeteor book where they use:
`Meteor.publish('posts', function(options) {
  return Posts.find({}, options);
});`

Comment: @ValentinZambelli please check what they are sending in options paramter. and if it solved your problem please the accept the answer